# Where can I find the names of Aupapuranas (or Atipuranas or Sthala puranas)?

Tags: puranas, reference-request

Apart from 18 Maha Puranas and 18 Upapuranas, there are Sthala Puranas which are known as Aupapuranas or Atipurans or Kula Puranas. Where can I find the list of Aupapuranas? How many Aupapuranas are there? Is there any Hindu sastra that gives a list of Aupapuranas? If possible, please add a link to any published Aupapurana (English translation), if available.

Comment: sthala puranas are embedded in 18 maha/upa puranas. The problem is translations of puranas available online don't cover the entire purana as translators choose to translate only those parts of puranas which are listed under chapter 92-109 of narada purana and ignore rest parts of purana. wisdomlib has dedicated page for every purana where it lists all manuscripts associated with maha/upa puranas. This includes many sthalapuranas/mahatmyas like Panduranga Mahatmya, etc. which though part of purana but excluded by translators.

Comment: @ekAntika In Wikipedia I saw a list where I found names such as Vasava Purana and Candi Purana. Candi Purana was composed by Sarala Das from Odisha in the 15th century. Vasava Purana is considered a very important text for Lingayets in Karnataka. Separate English translations are available. However, I am not sure whether these are really Aupapuranas. No source was cited in Wikipedia.

Comment: ok but those wd be mostly sectarian/regional lang puranas so i dont think there is going to be a standard list. But in such puranas what i have observed is that those puranas are retelling (~ 80% match) of the original sanskrit sthala puranas in local language